# Mongoose, Update an object inside an array which is inside another array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Is there a way to update and object inside and array which is also inside another array like in this example?

this is how the collection would be like:

```
{
  "_id": "5fd3966d2769d212dc0104a4",
  "Races": [
    {
      "_id": "5fd3966d2769dc12dc0105f4",
      "gpName": "Sakhir Grand Prix",
      "RaceResult": [
        {
          "_id": "5fd3966d2769dc12dc0105e0",
          "position": "First",
          "driverName": "Hamilton"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5fd3966d2769dc12dc0105e1",
          "position": "Second",
          "driverName": "Vettel"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5fd3966d2769dc12dc0105df",
      "gpName": "Abu Dhabi Grand Prix",
      "RaceResult": [
        {
          "_id": "5fd39452d2769dc12dc0105df",
          "position": "First",
          "driverName": "Bottas"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5fd3966d2769dc12dc0105e2",
          "position": "Second",
          "driverName": "Hamilton"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So If I want to change for example, "United States Grand Prix" instead of "Sakhir Grand Prix", I would go with:

```
StandingsModel.updateOne({ "Races._id": "5fd3966d2769dc12dc0105f4"}, {
        "$set": {
            "Races.$.gpName": 'United States Grand Prix'}
})
```

But how can I change the "driverName" or "position" value inside RaceResults?.

I've tried with setting:

(For clarification, in this example I wanna change the second driver name inside Abu Dhabi GP)

```
StandingsModel.updateOne({ "Races.RaceResults._id": "5fd3966d2769dc12dc0105e2"}, {
        "$set": {
            "Races.$.RaceResults.$.driverName": 'Vettel'}
})
```

But of course this don't work as expected and mongoose send back an error code 2.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`$[<identifier>]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#position-nested-arrays-filtered). Also there is an specific section called [Update Nested Arrays in Conjunction with $[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#position-nested-arrays-filtered).

You can use this way to filter the array looking for your `Race` id first and after your `RaceResult` id.

You can use this query:

```js
db.collection.update(
{ "_id": "5fd3966d2769d212dc0104a4" },
{ "$set": { "Races.$[race].RaceResult.$[result].driverName": "Vettel" } },
{ "arrayFilters": [ 
   { "race._id": "5fd3966d2769dc12dc0105df" },
   { "result.position": "Second" } ] 
})
```

The `$set` stage will modify the object into `Race` array that match the filter `race`. And inside race array, will filter by `result` filter.

That is: The query will get one race by its `id` using filter `race._id` and inside the race only the object where `position` is `Second` will be updated.

So the query will update the object you want. You can check an example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YHZxh5pvV94)